# Class with pointer members and memory assign

Tags: c++

I have a little problem with a class that contains pointer to `char`. This is the class.

```
//Header file
class NOTE{
private:
    char * m_Description;
public:
    NOTE();
    NOTE( string description );
    NOTE( const NOTE & copy );
    ~NOTE();

    void SetDescription( string description );
    string GetDescription() const;
};

//Cpp File
NOTE :: NOTE() : m_Description( nullptr ){ }

NOTE :: NOTE( string description ) 
      : m_Description( new char[ description.size() + 1 ] )
{
    strcpy( m_Description , description.c_str() );
}

NOTE :: ~NOTE(){ delete [] m_Description; }

NOTE :: NOTE( const NOTE & copy )
      : m_Description( new char[ strlen( copy.m_Description ) + 1 ] ) //Here my program fails
{
      strcpy( this->m_Description , copy.m_Description );
}

string NOTE :: GetDescription() const {
      return string( m_Description );
}

void NOTE :: SetDescription( string description ){
      strcpy( m_Description , description.c_str() );
}
```

The error appears when the program tries to copy a `NOTE` and it stops in the assignment of new memory for the pointer. Did you find any problem with the code?

Another doubt that I have is in the `SetDescription` method: Do I have to assign new memory for the pointer before I call `strcpy`?

Edit: my problem is not a compile problem, It's a runtime problem.

Comment: What is the error that appears?

Comment: Having a quick glance I have realized you're missing a right parenthesis at the end of this line `m_Description( new char[ description.size() + 1 ]`.

Comment: STOP. USING. `char*`!

Comment: I tried [this](http://cpp.sh/6ofv) and it works perfectly. I had to, as @WoozyCoder pointed out, add a right parenthesis.

Comment: This [test](http://cpp.sh/4diq) breaks and I pointed in the below comment/note.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the parenthesis, but It's just because I wrote a example class that represents the problem I have.

Comment: About your comment about not use char*, I use it because I'm creating a class that it can be read correctly from a binary file. However, If I use strings it wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue with your code, exactly in the line where it fails: your copy constructor passes a potential NULL pointer to `strlen` without any checks:

```
 m_Description( new char[ strlen( copy.m_Description ) + 1 ] ) // copy.m_Description may be NULL
```

This might as well explain your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the second question first, since you have a default constructor `NOTE()` which initializes the pointer to NULL, you should check if this pointer is NULL and if it is allocate memory or I believe you could have a segmentation fault.
**Edit**: As explained in comments checking for null is not enough since even if it has been allocated the size requires may differ

For the first question can you edit to display more information regarding how the program fails. Bear in mind you are accessing a private element (the char pointer) but this is allowed since it is the same class

Comment: NOTE: Even if the NOTE has been previously assigned, `m_Description` must be deleted and created (memory reservation) again since the new description does not have to have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Combining all comments and answers we can assert that

1. You are missing a `)` and the end of the line `m_Description( new char[ description.size() + 1 ]`.
2. Inside the method `SetDescription` you have to first check if `m_Description` is NULL. If it's not, delete the current memory reservation. In both cases reserve memory for the new description (`new char[ description.size() + 1 ]`).

Update

Here is an [example](http://cpp.sh/2lzwm).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of "Food for thought" things!!

1. Of course, do not mess up with character pointers, without having sufficient memory for them.
2. After the strcpy, do not forget to attach "\0" to the char*
3. Know that when you manage objects in free store, you've to implement an assignment operator, destructor, etc. a.k.a The Rule of Three/Five.
4. Before performing strcpy, please also check if the input is null or not!! (specially at the place where your code fails!!)

Comment: Your answers really worked me. I didn't know the rule of three/five. I already implemented it into my class. But I still not understanding the second suggestion. I mean, is not strcpy responsible of add the '\0' ? About the fourth suggestion, I don't get why I've to ask if the pointer is null or not, i.e I'm gonna change its value and it doesn't matters if is empty or not. Or do you mean I've to do it for the delete sentence?